# WebBrowser TargetFrameName value

Tags: vb.net, winforms, webbrowser-control

A WebBrowser example like this :

```
Private Sub Form4_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com")
End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property TargetFrameName As String

Private Sub WebBrowser1_Navigating(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.Navigating

    'Me.TargetFrameName = TargetFrameName
    Dim messageBoxVB As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    'MsgBox(e.TargetFrameName.ToString)

    messageBoxVB.AppendFormat("{0} = {1}", "Url", e.Url)
    messageBoxVB.AppendLine()
    messageBoxVB.AppendFormat("{0} = {1}", "TargetFrameName", e.TargetFrameName)
    messageBoxVB.AppendLine()
    messageBoxVB.AppendFormat("{0} = {1}", "Cancel", e.Cancel)
    messageBoxVB.AppendLine()
    MessageBox.Show(messageBoxVB.ToString(), "Navigating Event")

End Sub
```

The Messagebox shows:

```
Url= http://www.google.com
TargetFrameName=  
Cancel= False
```

My question is why there in no value or name for the `TargetFrameName`?

Comment: The TargetFrameName gets the name of the iframe in which the new document will be loaded. It has value for an iframe tag which its name attribute is set.